# Is there a way to automatically drop delimiters when using a tidyr separate with a regex positive lookahead?

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I'm trying to separate a messy free text field in which full names have been split by multiple delimiters. I've been able to split these into first names and surnames using the `separate()` function. However, the positive lookahead regex I've used leaves the delimitor in the `surname`. Is there an efficient way this could be automatically removed?

Example:

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

mydf <- tribble(
  ~Name,
  "Ben,Smith",
  "Amy:White",
  "Mark|Williams"
)

mydf_split <- mydf %>% separate(Name, c("first_name","surname"), sep = '(?=,|\\:|\\|)')
```

This returns the following dataframe.

```
    first_name  surname
1   Ben         ,Smith
2   Amy         :White
3   Mark        |Williams
```

I would like to remove the `,` `:`, and `|` from the beginning of the `surname`s.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a character class:

```r
mydf %>% separate(Name, c("first_name","surname"), sep = '[,:|]')
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   first_name surname 
#   <chr>      <chr>   
# 1 Ben        Smith   
# 2 Amy        White   
# 3 Mark       Williams
```

The `(?=,|\:|\|)` regex is a *positive lookahead* that is a *non-consuming* pattern matching a location immediately followed with `,`, `:` or `|` chars. Non-consuming means the chars matched with this pattern remain in the resulting chunks after splitting. You need to remove them after splitting, so you need to *consume* them, and here, a character class without a lookahead is the most natural regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

The default separator of `[^[:alnum:]]+` works with the data in the question

```
mydf %>% separate(Name, c("first_name", "surname"))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  first_name surname 
  <chr>      <chr>   
1 Ben        Smith   
2 Amy        White   
3 Mark       Williams
```

If you want to add other acceptable characters then just include them in that regex.  For example to include single quote, comma, period and space

```
mydf <- data.frame(Name = c("Pat:O'Neil", "Joe|Smith, Jr."))
mydf %>% separate(Name, c("first_name", "surname"), sep = "[^[:alnum:]',. ]+")
##   first_name    surname
## 1        Pat     O'Neil
## 2        Joe Smith, Jr.
```